# RadGridView in Silverlight 4.0 is not showing data

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have a **Silverlight 4.0** page in my web application. There is a **RadGridView** for showing a chart based on the grid data.

As per my logic i can create chart using the grid data and save that in my database. When i navigate to another page and get back to chart, i could not see data in the grid but i can view the chart only.

I need help on this as I am new to **Telerik RadGridView** and chart controls.

thanks in advance....

Comment: Show some code of what you've done so far so we can get a better idea of what is happening and what is expected.

Comment: @Nkosi I am doing support work for a client application. The code base already developed there.